# Yii2 how to rewrite url without controller name

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2

I am rewriting my yii2 website urls.In my config file i added

```
'<category_name>-<controller>-<category_id>'=>'<controller>/index'
```

and in the url i just passed the parameters like

```
<?=Url::to(['shop/index','category_id'=>1,'category_name'=>'clothes'])?>
```

And my url comes like

```
https://example.com/clothes-shop-1
```

This is  what i am getting. But i need something like

```
https://example.com/clothes-1
```

for that i just changed the rule like this

```
'<category_name>-<category_id>'=>'<controller>/index'
```

But that time rewriting doesn't working.How can i remove the controller name from that url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does system know, what controller is needed to proceed URL? In first example

```
'<category_name>-<controller>-<category_id>'=>'<controller>/index'
```

There is a controller name. In second

```
'<category_name>-<category_id>'=>'<controller>/index'
```

No controller name.
So you need to tell it. Try

```
'<category_name>-<category_id>'=>'shop/index'
```

Comment: @AbhijithAbhi please, mark answer as correct.